# Выборка из laravel не преобразуется в массив

Tags: php, laravel

Делаю выборку из БД в laravel.

```
$aComments = DB::table('Comments')
            ->where('Name', $name)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

После перебираю массив $aComments

```
foreach ($aComments as $comment) {
    dd(gettype($aJoinCommentUser), gettype($comment));
}
```

И у меня выводит, что $aComments это array, а $comment это object

Не пойму мочему

```
->get()
->toArray()
```

не преобразует выборку в массив. И как реализовать, что бы массив был целиком массивом.

Comment: Потому что вы получаете массив объектов вместо Collection через вызов этого метода

Comment: @DanielProtopopov А возможно каким то методом, получить массив массивов?

Comment: По разному. Можно (array)$comment, возможно ли $comment->toArray() ли - не знаю, проверяйте. Тип объекта не известен?